# How can I get access to this repo?

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I keep trying to push files to my github repo on my "user21" acoount.

```
git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to user21/simple-site.git denied to 
user1212114.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user21/simple-site/': The 
requested URL returned error: 403
```

but it says that I need permission from an account called "user1212114" that I created ages ago, and have forgotten the password too.

How do I remove the old account and fix this error?

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to use a different account that does have access to this repository?

Comment: @Schwern No, I'd like to use the account "user21" but everytime I try and push my commits to the repo I created, it keeps saying perms are being denied by this old account I created ages ago

Comment: You'd like to switch from using `user1212114` to access the repository to using `user21`?

Comment: @Schwern that's right

Comment: @Schwern any ideas how I could fix it?

Comment: How Git stores https credentials is a bit of a mess. It's different from installation to installation. You're using git-bash? It's often easier to just switch to ssh with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user21/sample-site.git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Powershell instead of the git bash terminal which worked.

Answer (score 0):

How Git stores https credentials is a bit of a mess. It's different from installation to installation. It's often easier to switch to ssh with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user21/sample-site.git`. [Github has a guide how to set up ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) and once you've followed that things are a lot easier.

---

In order to fix what you've got, you've got find out how you're storing your https credentials. Just putting your password in a file would be insecure, passwords are never stored in a recoverable form, anybody who got the file would know your password. It needs to use something secure.

You can check what with `git config --global credential.helper`. If it's Git For Windows (aka Git Bash) you're probably using `wincred` which is the native Windows Credential Manager. If so, you'd open the Windows Credential Manager, find the credentials for that Github URL, and change them.

I've never used the Windows Credental Manager, but [here's a tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-windows-8-1s-credential-manager/).